# C++ large multidimensional-arrays on stack

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

My simulation tries to predict the demand on a system for a long period of time ... the output results in a very large 4D array (I use the 4 dimensions to minimise the chance of an error when the data is written to the array i.e. I can understand it better this way!).

The array size will be 25x4x3x20000 and I need it to be at least an (unsigned int) but I know that the stack can't handle this amount of data.

```
unsigned int ar[25][4][3][2000];
```

I have been looking around and found different solutions. However I am still undecided on which one to implement. So my question is: which one is better in term of performance and good practice:

1. **Use a vector of arrays:** as described in [stackoverflow.com/questions/18991765](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991765/vector-of-vectors-reserve) ... But then any idea on how to convert for a 4D dimensions?

> `std::vector< std::array<int, 5> > vecs;
>   vecs.reserve(N);`

2. **Use a 4D vector and push_back()**: I didn't use this because I know the final size of the array and I wanted to prevent many push_backs operations.
3. **Create the array on the heap**: as described in 
   [stackoverflow.com/questions/675817](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675817/how-do-i-create-an-array-in-c-which-is-on-the-heap-instead-of-the-stack)

Any other suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Just ask if you need more links to grasp what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that `[2000]` in the final dimension. Just make that dynamic.

Have your 3D array as such:

```
using arr3d = std::array<std::array<std::array<unsigned int, 25>, 4>, 3>;
```

and then the vector for the fourth dimension:

```
std::vector<arr3d> ar;
ar.reserve(N); // for optimization
```

Comment: You've rearranged the order of the array dimensions. What you have looks like `ar[2000][3][4][25]`

Comment: @DeiDei great I will try as you have suggested ... In this case if I want to use a pointer to manipulate my array I create it to the vector `vector<arr3d> *ptr_ar = &ar;` then I can access the array easily with `ptr_ar->at(1)` ... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, sure. But you might wanna look into references, e.g. `vector<arr3d>& ref_ar = ar;` and then `ref_ar.at(1)`. It's just safer this way. Also make sure you fix the dimensions as @Blastfurnace mentioned. I'll edit the answer in a bit.