# Trying to understand the access operator of a Matrix Multiplication in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the access operator for a Matrix Multiplication.

```cpp
template<typename T> 
class Matrix44 
{ 
public: 
    Matrix44() {} 
    // The next two lines are totally confusing for me
    const T* operator [] (uint8_t i) const { return m[i]; }
    T* operator [] (uint8_t i) { return m[i]; }
    // initialize the coefficients of the matrix with the coefficients of the identity matrix
    T m[4][4] = {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}}; // Why can you do this m[4][4]
}; 
 
typedef Matrix44<float> Matrix44f;
```

So what I understood is that they defined an own access operator for accessing the matrix indices:

```cpp
Matrx44f mat; 
mat[0][3] = 1.f;
```

But how does that relate to their defintion

```cpp
...
const T* operator [] (uint8_t i) const { return m[i]; }
T* operator [] (uint8_t i) { return m[i]; }
```

Thank you very much for helping a C++ noob <3

Source: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry/matrices

Comment: Honestly that’s a fairly poor matrix implementation which leaks implementation details via its interface. A *proper* implementation doesn’t do this.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but that is good to know then I won't dig deeper :D

Comment: Is the point you're missing that pointers can be indexed like arrays? (If `p` is a pointer, `p[k]` is equivalent to `*(p + k)`, and `mat[0]` is a pointer.) For more mystery, consider that you can also write `3[mat[0]] = 1.f;`...

Comment: @KonradRudolph Have you looked through the header files for the STL on any major implementations? Not sure how your definition of *proper* would apply there.

Comment: @molbdnilo haha your last sentence is great. More mystery is adding up ;)

Comment: @AdrianMole not yet I am quite at the beginning of the C++ Odyssey :D

Comment: @AdrianMole I’m not sure what you’re referring to. There’s no matrix implementation in the standard library, and it wouldn’t implement the element access operator via this hack.

Comment: @Konrad My comment was more about the *leaks implementation details* part. I agree that this is a poor matrix implementation but not that "leaking details" is inherently bad. What about header-only libraries?

Comment: @AdrianMole Header-only libraries are a necessary evil since C++ hasn’t got proper modules (yet). It has little to nothing to do with the topic at hand (API design) and only serves to confuse OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quite a few people have already pointed out it is quite a **poor matrix implementation**: It let's you make assumptions about the internal implementation and has quite a few flaws. But I would lie if I said I would not have already seen implementations like this in research codes. ;) Instead of bashing the implementation I would like to briefly point out how it works as nonetheless it shows a few particularities of C++.

**Overview**

```
// Class for a generic data type T (e.g. T = float)
template<typename T> 
class Matrix44 { 
public: 
  // Constructor
  Matrix44() {
    return;
  } 
  // Access operator for constant objects
  const T* operator [] (uint8_t i) const {
    return m[i];
  }
  // Access operator for non-constant objects
  T* operator [] (uint8_t i) {
    return m[i];
  }
  // Declaration of a stack-allocated array as class member
  T m[4][4] 
  // Initialisation of this class member
  = {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}};
};

// Alias Matrix44f for a matrix of floats (T = float)
typedef Matrix44<float> Matrix44f;
```

**Stack allocated arrays**

In C++ unlike in other programming languages one can allocate arrays on the [stack](https://people.eecs.ku.edu/%7Ejrmiller/Courses/JavaToC++/StackAllocatedArrays.html) as well as on the [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675817/how-do-i-create-an-array-in-c-which-is-on-the-heap-instead-of-the-stack). A stack allocated one-dimensional array can (of integers) be declared as

```
int v[3];
```

while

```
int m[2][3];
```

would be the declaration of a [**multidimensional** (in this case two-dimensional) row-major **array**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-c-cpp/) which can be initialised with

```
int m[2][3] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

(similar to how you could initialise a vector of vectors with an [initialiser list](https://www.techiedelight.com/initialize-two-dimensional-vector-cpp/)) and whose elements can then be accessed with a similar syntax `m[i][j]` (also similar to a vector of vectors `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, Watch out: No out-of-bound checks!).

As you can see your class is only a **wrapper** for a such a stack-allocated two-dimensional array of a generic type `T`,

```
T m[4][4];
```

a so called `template class`. Instantiating the class as `Matrix44<float>` makes it a matrix of `T = float` while for a matrix `Matrix44<int>` the underlying data type would be `int`. With `typedef Matrix44<float> Matrix44f` at the bottom a new alias for this data type was create. So one can declare a variable `Matrix44f mat`.

Stack-allocated means that its size is quite limited compared to a heap-allocated array which isn't very prohibiting for a `4x4` array though (but why would you not extend this implementation at least to `NxN`?). Furthermore the way it is written it does not even have a proper constructor (`Matrix44() {}`) but is instead default-initialised with an identity matrix

```
{{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}}
```

(why would somebody do that?).

**Operator []**

C++ gives you the possibility to overload operators. So one can define (overload) basic operations such as addition `operator +`, multiplication `operator *`, comparisons etc. Similarly one can also overload `[]` (but only with a single argument and therefore numerical libraries such as `Eigen` opt to overload the `()` operator instead), `()` and `,`. But there is no such thing as a `[][]` overload! In order to allow a matrix access from outside the class with `[][]` similar to the stack-allocated array it was chosen to write an **operator `[]` that returns a pointer to the first element of the second dimension** of the underlying two-dimensional array at the corresponding index `i` of the first dimension `m[i][0]`: `return m[i]` is equivalent to `return &m[i][0]`. One can apply then the  **operator `[]` of the pointer** `p[j]` which is equivalent to `*(p+j)` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) for more details) to move this pointer by j-entries to access the element `m[i][j]`. (This is sort of similar to using a vector-of-vectors instead of a stack-allocated-array, returning a `std::vector<T>&` from the operator `[]` and then using the `[]` operator of the vector to access the precise element.)

Member functions can be declared constant (see the `const` after the argument list) which means they can also be called for constant objects while if not declared constant they can only be called for non-constant objects. For constant objects the constant version is called while for non-constant objects the non-constant implementation is called ([**`const` overloading**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-and-const-functions/)). In order to **allow assignments** the **non-constant version**

```
T* operator [] (uint8_t i) {
  return m[i];
}
```

returns a non-constant pointer `T*` which can be modified while the constant implementation returns a pointer to a constant variable `const T*`.

```
const T* operator [] (uint8_t i) const { 
  return m[i];
}
```

This is the reason why there are two of these implementations. For a constant object the latter one will be called which does not allow assignment (but you can read the element `1, 2` with `m[1][2]`) while for a non-constant one the first one which allows assignment (e.g. `m[1][2] = 1` will set the element `1, 2` to `1`).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and for taking the time to give such a thorough and nice answer! I didn't think my question would reveal such a deep problem. It certainly took time to formulate all this. For this I apologiz, but I deeply appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome, always glad if I can help!

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that the only value of this class is to give value semantics to a C-array and that is not yet achieved with the shown code. (Sort of what `std::array<T, N>` does.)

Besides that, this is a bad implementation that relies in pointer decay, the reference to the 4-element array (once you take the first index), decays into an pointer in your implementation.
At best the decay looses useful type information.

So, as it is, `m[i]` returns a reference to a C-array and it is later decayed into a pointer by the return type of `operator[]` of the class.
A better implementation could simply be `decltype(auto) operator[](int i){return m[i];}`.

If you want a more explicit description of what is going on you can do

```
    using reference = T(&)[4]; // reference to a 4-element subarray
    reference const operator[](int i) const { return m[i]; }
    reference       operator[](int i)       { return m[i]; }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EjbWY691x

At this point, it might be better to rely in an existing good wrapper and simply say

```
template<class T> using Matrix44 = std::array<std::array<T, 4>, 4>;
```

If the initialization to identity is important (not a good idea IMO)...

```
template<typename T> 
class Matrix44 
{ 
public: 
    Matrix44() {} 
    // The next two lines are totally confusing for me
    decltype(auto) operator [] (uint8_t i) const { return m[i]; }
    decltype(auto) operator [] (uint8_t i)       { return m[i]; }
    // initialize the coefficients of the matrix with the coefficients of the identity matrix
    std::array<std::array<T, 4>, 4> m = {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}};
}; 
 
typedef Matrix44<float> Matrix44f;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation for a beginner and especially taking your precious time to write an answer! And especially thanks for writing it down to the website to illustrate the process. Didnt know about that tool. Certainly helpful for me in the future!
It's really cool that C++ is so versatile, but with that I see that I still have a long way to go to master C++ :D